# cxf-java2ws-plugin generates an input parameter in wsdl for no input parameter method in java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am using cxf-java2ws-plugin version 3.1.12.
The following method, which takes no input params,

```
    @WebMethod public @WebResult(name = "owner") Collection<Owner>  
         getAllOwners();
```

Results in the following wsdl part:
.......
.......

```
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllOwners">
       <wsdl:input name="getAllOwners" message="tns:getAllOwners">
       </wsdl:input>
       <wsdl:output name="getAllOwnersResponse"    
               message="tns:getAllOwnersResponse">
       </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

.......

```
    <wsdl:message name="getAllOwners">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllOwners">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
```

.......

What can be done in order to generate the wsdl correctly (without input params)?

Comment: There is no "input params" there. What you see is an "input message", that is needed to initiate the execution of your operation...

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot. No prob with the wsdl. The problem was in another component.